# how to extract data from json using oracle text index

Tags: json, oracle

I have a table, which has an Oracle text index. I created the index because I need an extra fast search. The table contains JSON data. Oracle json_textcontains works very poorly so I tried to play with CONTAINS (json_textcontains is rewritten to CONTAINS actually if we have a look into query plan).

I want to find all jsons by given class_type and id of value but Oracle looks all over JSON without looking that class_type and id should be in one JSON section i.e. it deals with JSON not like structured data but like a huge string.

Well formatted JSON looks like this:

```
{
     "class":[
              {
               "class_type":"ownership",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"1"}]
              },
              {
               "class_type":"country",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]
              },
              ,
              {
               "class_type":"features",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"15"},{"nm":"id","value":"20"}]
              }
             ]
    }
```

The second one which shouldn't be found looks like this:

```
{
     "class":[
              {
               "class_type":"ownership",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"18"}]
              },
              {
               "class_type":"country",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"11"}]
              },
              ,
              {
               "class_type":"features",
               "values":[{"nm":"id","value":"7"},{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]
              }
             ]
    }
```

Please see how to reproduce what I'm trying to achieve:

```
create table perso.json_data(id number, data_val blob);

insert into perso.json_data 

values(
1,
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"1"}]},{"class_type":"country","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]},{"class_type":"features","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"15"},{"nm":"id","value":"20"}]}]}')
);


insert into perso.json_data values(
2,
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"18"}]},{"class_type":"country","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"11"}]},{"class_type":"features","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"7"},{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]}]}')
)
;

commit;


ALTER TABLE perso.json_data
ADD CONSTRAINT check_is_json
 CHECK (data_val IS JSON (STRICT));

 CREATE INDEX perso.json_data_idx ON json_data (data_val)
 INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
 PARAMETERS ('section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)');


select *
from perso.json_data

where ctxsys.contains(data_val, '(640 INPATH(/class/values/value)) and (country inpath (/class/class_type))')>0
```

The query returns 2 rows but I expect to get only the record where id = 1.

How can I use a full text index with the ability to search without the error I highlighted, without using JSON_TABLE?

There is no options to put data in relational format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the text index directly to try to solve this kind of problem. It's not what it's designed for..

In 12.2.0.1.0 this should work for you (and yes it does use a specialized version of the text index under the covers, but it also applies selective post filtering to ensure the results are correct)..

```
SQL> create table json_data(id number, data_val blob)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into json_data values(
  2    1,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"1"}]},{"class_type":"cou
ntry","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]},{"class_type":"features","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"15"},{"nm":"id","valu
e":"20"}]}]}')
  3  )
  4  /

1 row created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |           |     1 |   100 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | JSON_DATA |       |       |            |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> insert into json_data values(
  2    2,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"18"}]},{"class_type":"co
untry","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"11"}]},{"class_type":"features","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"7"},{"nm":"id","value
":"640"}]}]}')
  3  )
  4  /

1 row created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |           |     1 |   100 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | JSON_DATA |       |       |            |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> commit
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL> ALTER TABLE json_data
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT check_is_json
  3   CHECK (data_val IS JSON (STRICT))
  4  /

Table altered.

SQL> CREATE SEARCH INDEX json_SEARCH_idx ON json_data (data_val) for JSON
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> set autotrace on explain
SQL> --
SQL> set lines 256 trimspool on pages 50
SQL> --
SQL> select ID, json_query(data_val, '$' PRETTY)
  2    from JSON_DATA
  3  /

        ID
----------
JSON_QUERY(DATA_VAL,'$'PRETTY)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------
         1
{
  "class" :
  [
    {
      "class_type" : "ownership",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "class_type" : "country",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "640"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "class_type" : "features",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "15"
        },
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "20"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

         2
{
  "class" :
  [

        ID
----------
JSON_QUERY(DATA_VAL,'$'PRETTY)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------
    {
      "class_type" : "ownership",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "18"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "class_type" : "country",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "11"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "class_type" : "features",
      "values" :
      [
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "7"
        },
        {
          "nm" : "id",
          "value" : "640"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3213740116

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |     2 |  4030 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| JSON_DATA |     2 |  4030 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

SQL> select ID, to_clob(data_val)
  2    from json_data
  3   where JSON_EXISTS(data_val,'$?(exists(@.class?(@.values.value == $VALUE && @.class_type == $TYPE)))' passing '640'
 as "VALUE", 'country' as "TYPE")
  4  /

        ID TO_CLOB(DATA_VAL)
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 {"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"1"}]},{"class_
           type":"country","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]},{"class_type":"features","
           values":[{"nm":"id","value":"15"},{"nm":"id","value":"20"}]}]}



Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3248304200

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                 |     1 |  2027 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| JSON_DATA       |     1 |  2027 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   DOMAIN INDEX              | JSON_SEARCH_IDX |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(JSON_EXISTS2("DATA_VAL" FORMAT JSON , '$?(exists(@.class?(@.values.value
              == $VALUE && @.class_type == $TYPE)))' PASSING '640' AS "VALUE" , 'country' AS "TYPE"
              FALSE ON ERROR)=1)
   2 - access("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("JSON_DATA"."DATA_VAL",'{640} INPATH
              (/class/values/value) and {country} INPATH (/class/class_type)')>0)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

SQL> select ID, TO_CLOB(DATA_VAL)
  2    from JSON_DATA d
  3   where exists (
  4           select 1
  5             from JSON_TABLE(
  6                    data_val,
  7                    '$.class'
  8                    columns (
  9                      CLASS_TYPE VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.class_type',
 10                      NESTED PATH '$.values.value'
 11                      columns (
 12                        "VALUE"  VARCHAR2(32) path '$'
 13                      )
 14                    )
 15                  )
 16            where CLASS_TYPE = 'country' and "VALUE" = '640'
 17        )
 18  /

        ID TO_CLOB(DATA_VAL)
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 {"class":[{"class_type":"ownership","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"1"}]},{"class_
           type":"country","values":[{"nm":"id","value":"640"}]},{"class_type":"features","
           values":[{"nm":"id","value":"15"},{"nm":"id","value":"20"}]}]}



Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1621266031

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |           |     1 |  2027 |    32   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                 |           |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL     | JSON_DATA |     2 |  4054 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   FILTER                |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |    JSONTABLE EVALUATION |           |       |       |            |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM JSON_TABLE( :B1, '$.class' COLUMNS(
              "CLASS_TYPE" VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.class_type' NULL ON ERROR , NESTED PATH
              '$.values.value' COLUMNS( "VALUE" VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$' NULL ON ERROR ) ) )
              "P" WHERE "CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"(:B2,'({country} INPATH (/class/class_type))
              and ({640} INPATH (/class/values/value))')>0 AND "P"."CLASS_TYPE"='country'
              AND "P"."VALUE"='640'))
   3 - filter("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"(:B1,'({country} INPATH
              (/class/class_type)) and ({640} INPATH (/class/values/value))')>0)
   4 - filter("P"."CLASS_TYPE"='country' AND "P"."VALUE"='640')

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

SQL>
```